# PlayFramework 2.4.x ide debug

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework-2.0

Is that possible to debug  in playframework 2.4.x ? (x = 3 in my case) ?

IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.5

I'm following this link/doc: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/IDE

> Create a new Run Configuration – From the main menu, select Run ->
>   Edit Configurations Click on the + to add a new configuration From the
>   list of configurations, choose “SBT Task” In the “tasks” input box,
>   simply put “run” Apply changes and select OK. Now you can choose “Run”
>   from the main Run menu and run your application
>
> You can easily start a debugger session for a Play application using
>   default Run/Debug Configuration settings.

No luck so far for IntelliJ IDEA. When run as / press debug it does not drop me to debug break-poitns in IDE in my controller code when I got my get/post requests.

UPDATE:
 One more try with same result (see screenshot) with adding play2 debug configuration (following: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/getting-started-with-play-2-x.html):

[image]

If I change `2.4.3` to `2.4.2`:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.4.3")
```

or in: `addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-fork-run-plugin" % "2.4.3")`

same result.Or if I put JVML levelt to java 7.

It will be hard to convince a team to migrate a project from tomcat to play :) No `out-of-the box` magic.

And that `"Setting up Play fork run ... "` massage in logs that eats all processors for many seconds makes it even harder.

Comment: There shouldn't be any problems. I am also using IntelliJ with Play and can start my application with Debug configuration, set breakpoints and they are all being hit. You can post a screenshot with your debug configuration. Also inspect the starting of your application - which parameters are being provided to the Java process?

Comment: as was suggested on doc page I do it with sbt-task: the params are: -Xms512M -Xmx1024M -Xss1M -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:MaxPermSize=256M  (i use jdk 8 - so I also got msg like "Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256M; support was removed in 8.0" when starting)

Answer (score 0):

Something weired happanes anyhow.
Inititally I have createad my project from Play Activator as typical scala-play project.

But now when I created it from IDE  New->Project->Scala->Play 2.x, then it works with debugging on out of the box.

If one figures out what is difference would be nice (even if that guy is me, from the Future). Seems guys from JetBrains care more about IDE integratiion than guys from TypeSafe ;).

Maybe the reason is in `plugins.sbt`

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.3.8")
```

that what my IDE uses by default.

Or maybe it has somethign to do with [this routing and IoC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30543960/play-framework-for-scala-compilation-errortype-application-is-not-a-member-of)

For now I'm suttisfied. Thinking that 2.4.x is not ready to be used (at least not in convicing someone in something).

### Update

Comment the following out and breakpoints work again:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-fork-run-plugin" % "2.4.6")
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this issue? 

I am running into this same issue. I am not able to debug any activator ui template projects within IntelliJ, and I have tried all the advice and suggestions I could find online from Play's website, IntelliJ's website, and community support. Everyone says debugging should work fine within IntelliJ. I have found that it is only when I create my own Play application using IntelliJ to create it, that debugging finally works.

Comment: Use older version so far. Last one sucks. Not sure how it possible, suck for so long (not being fixed).

Comment: What I found is that when I comment out this addSbtPlugin(), I am able to debug within IntelliJ, addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-fork-run-plugin" % "2.4.6"). I do not know why at this point. The two activator ui templates I have tried both have this. When I create a Play app from scratch using IntelliJ, it does not have it.